# how to take users off ad groups user is part of

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We are trying to take user off all ad groups when user is termed in HR Database. I have the termination of user account figured out but how can we take that specific user our of all assigned group using powershell.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and with what results?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to retrieve the `ADUser` object before deleting it from ActiveDirectory, examine its `.MemberOf` property, and then run through those groups with the `Remove-ADGroupMember` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started you need to get the user's `memberOf` and the user's `distinguishedName`

In the following example I am getting the user by their logon name (`samaccountname`) You can use whatever attribute you want as long as it returns the correct user:

```
$testUser = "Test User"

$user = Get-ADUser -filter {Samaccountname -eq $testUser} -Properties memberof, distinguishedName
$Groups = $user.MemberOf
$DN = $user.DistinguishedName
```

Then in order to remove the user from their current membership, you can just put it in a `foreach`:

```
foreach($group in $groups)
{
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $DN -Identity $group -Confirm:$false
}
```

The `-Confirm:$false` is to suppress the warning about removal. You might want to remove that part during testing

Answer (score 0):

Many will tell you to look at the user's `memberOf` attribute. That will work just fine in most cases.

However, `memberOf` only shows groups with a scope of 'Universal' on any domain in the forest, or 'Global' groups on the same domain. It will not show groups with a 'Domain Local' scope (regardless of domain), or 'Global' groups on other domains.

To guarantee you find all groups the user is a member of, you need to search every domain in your forest for groups that the user is a member of:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$user = Get-ADUser "theuser"

$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains
$groups = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($domain in $domains) {
    $groups.AddRange(@(Get-ADGroup -filter {member -eq $user.DistinguishedName} -Server $domain))
}
```

Then `$groups` has the list of groups, and you can use `Remove-ADGroupMember` to remove the user from those groups.

Again, this is only relevant to you if you either:

1. Have more than one domain in your forest, and/or
2. Use 'Domain Local' groups